# Is it true that the space $H^{1}(I)$ is contained compactly in $L^{2}(I)$?

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

Consider $I$ a limited range. Is it true that the space $H^{1}(I)$ is contained compactly in $L^{2}(I)$?

I ask this question because Brezis, the author states that $W^{1,1}(I)$ is contained compactly in $L^{2}(I)$. What about $H^{1} (I) = W^{1,2}(I)$?

Comment: $H^1\subset W^{1,1} \Subset L^2$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you very much, from the bottom of my heart. It helped me, I hadn't thought about the continuous inclusion of $L^2$ in $L^{1}$.

Comment: only for bounded domains! yw